# Обратная анимация

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте. Сделал анимацию при наведении мыши двух блоков. Не могу додуматься как сделать обратный плавный эффект при убирании курсора.

https://jsfiddle.net/ynbfn515/ может надо было с переходами это сделать?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none; 
color: red;}

@keyframes vras{
    100% {
        left: 100px;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(.9);
    }
}
@keyframes vras2{
 0%{
  transform: scale(.9);
  }
    100% {
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
p{
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
p:hover{
    animation: vras 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
p:hover+h1{
    animation: vras2 1s .7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
h1{
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
     <p>Вопрос</p>
     <h1>Ответ</h1>
```

Comment: чтобы анимация была плавная после выхода курсора за область элемента, нужно вешать css transition эффект на класс без `:hover`, а при наведении изменять состояние элемента

Comment: Насколько я знаю, свойство `transition` позволяет возвращать в исходное положение элемент в любой момент анимации... Если задача прям конкретно в этом, то лучше использовать `transition` для анимации. А свойство `animation`, ну, вроде бы, оно просто анимирует. По факту. Можно разве что остановить её свойством `animation-play-state`. Хотя наверняка через библиотечки какие-нибудь можно этим манипулировать.. Но конкретно ради такой задачи, повторюсь, можно и `transition` ограничиться.

Comment: @VostokSisters Что-то пита этого? https://jsfiddle.net/ynbfn515/1/

Answer (score 3):

В комментариях я писал о transition. Вот, как бы сделал я. 
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/PWqagz).
Ниже привел код. Твой код я комментировал, а не стирал.
Собственно, нужно было ещё добавить какой-нибудь бек-элемент, который бы служил "пусковым элементом" для анимации, ведь если водить мышкой по тому месту, где раньше был `p`, то анимация будет дергаться. Это напомнило мне [урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kK-cA99SA0&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4LvJ8VctoXnPI0dtE40wfid) одного из моих любимых web-ютуберов. Рекомендую его посмотреть, он рассказывает (в том видео по ссылке) о `transition`, в том числе и про "поддергивания" при ховере и тоже использует фоновый элемент для решения этой проблемы. Дальше в плейлисте, если будет интересно, то популярно расскажет про свойство `animation`. Полезно.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  color: red;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px dotted orangered;
}
/* @keyframes vras{
    100% {
        left: 100px;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(.9);
    }
}
@keyframes vras2{
 0%{
  transform: scale(.9);
  }
    100% {
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
} */

p {
  left: 0;
  /*     margin-left: 100px; */
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s, opacity 1s ease 0s;
}
.wrap:hover p {
  /*     animation: vras 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(100px, 0px) scale(0.9);
}
.wrap:hover + h1 {
  /*     animation: vras2 1s .7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1.1);
  transition: transform 1s ease 0.7s, opacity 1s ease 0.7s;
}
h1 {
  /*     left: 100px; */
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  /*     margin-left: 100px; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  transform: translate(100px, 0px) scale(.9);
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s, opacity 1s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <p>Вопрос</p>
</div>
<h1>Ответ</h1>
```